# How to Create a Version-Independent and Scheme-Agnostic Build Script for Swift Package using Xcode and Swift Build?

Tags: swift, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager, swift-package

Consider the following code to verify the compilation of some swift package (for the Swift Package Manager)

```
xcodebuild \
  -scheme name-Package \
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=17.0,name=iPhone 15' \
  -configuration Debug
```

And the equivalent `swift build` command:

```
swift build -Xswiftc -warnings-as-errors -Xswiftc "-sdk" -Xswiftc "$(xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path)" -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-ios15.0-simulator"
```

**Questions:**

1. Would it be possible to make this Xcode/Simulator version independent, so that I won't have to include the version of the SDK in each command? i.e. remove this line from the 1st command: `Simulator,OS=17.0,name=iPhone 15` and remove this one from the 2nd one: `x86_64-apple-ios15.0-simulator`
2. Would it be possible to remove the `scheme` name from the 1st command, i.e. `name-Package`, or discover it in some way and paste the scheme containing the `Package` word, so that the `xcodebuild` will try to build the whole package and not just some single target in that package.

**Motivation:**
Create a generic build script that can work on any Swift Package repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PACKAGE_SCHEME=$(xcodebuild -list | (awk '/Schemes:/ {p=1; next} p && NF; !p {p=0}' | grep "Package" || xcodebuild -list | awk '/Schemes:/ {p=1; next} p && NF; !p {p=0}' | head -1) | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//')
xcodebuild \
  -scheme "$PACKAGE_SCHEME" \
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone" \
  -configuration Debug
```

It works as follows:

1. The first line detects the scheme to use, it's either the one with `Package` suffix or the first scheme
2. That scheme is inserted into the xcodebuild command that does the actual building.